# Matching Wrapper+Canvas+Div to an Image's Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I'm using heatmap.js in Google Apps Script and I am trying to resize the heatmap canvas (where I can actually plot points) to fit an image. How can I change the javascript or styling to make this work?

**CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/51h2guL9/**

- The `wrapper` has a black border.
- The heatmap `div` has a blue border.
- The `canvas` has a red border.

**How it Should Work:** I should be able to mark the heatmap anywhere on the image. The wrapper, heatmap div and canvas should all be sized based on the size of the image.

**How it Currently Works:** I can only mark the heatmap inside the blue/black border. My javascript resizes the canvas to fit the image, but not the bounds of the heatmap.

**What I've Tried:** You can see in the fiddle how I've tried to change what the javascript is resizing (lines 88-90).I also thought about using the using the image as the `background-image` of the `heatmap` div but the sizing wasn't right and I wanted to be able to save the heatmap and image as one layer (for printing/saving). I also tried changing the size of the image (line 101) but anything above 55% would cut the image off.

The screenshot below is just for reference, but the full working code is in the fiddle. I have it all under HTML because that's how it works in Google Apps Script.

[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/assets/js/heatmap.min.js"></script>
   <style>

   html, body {
     width:  100%;
     height: 100%;
  }

  html { 
    color: #333;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }

  .wrapper { 
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.03); 
    border:3px solid black; 
  }

  .heatmap { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid blue; 
 }

 .canvas {
   border:3px solid red; 
 }

  </style>

  </head>

 <body>
   <button class="clear">Clear</button>
   <button onclick="printPage()" class="print-btn no-print" style="">Print</button>
   <p id="coords"></p>
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper"> <!-- black box on web app-->
      <div id="heatmap" class = "heatmap" style="position: relative;"> <!-- blue box on web app-->
      <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas> <!-- red box on web app-->
    </div> 
  </div>


<script>



//CREATE HEATMAP
  window.onload = function() {
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
      container: document.querySelector('.heatmap'),
      gradient: {
        '.25': 'black',
        '.5': 'red',
        '.75': 'white'
      },
      radius: 20
    });

    document.querySelector('.wrapper').onclick = function(ev) {
      heatmapInstance.addData({
        x: ev.layerX,
        y: ev.layerY,
        value: 1
      });
    };

     document.querySelector('.clear').onclick = function() {
       //heatmapInstance._renderer._clear();
       heatmapInstance.setData({data:[]}); 
      };

//RESIVE CANVAS TO FIT IMAGE
  //http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/1135/
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');  //v1
  //var canvas = document.getElementById('heatmap'); //v2
  //var canvas = document.getElementById('wrapper');  //v3
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
      ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    var imageObj = new Image();


  imageObj.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = imageObj.width; // version 2
    canvas.height = imageObj.height;  // version 2  
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj,0,0); // version 2
    //ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width * 0.5, imageObj.height * 0.5); //version 1

  };
  imageObj.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Soccer_Field_Transparant.svg/1200px-Soccer_Field_Transparant.svg.png';

 };


//MOUSE COORDINATES
//works inside heatmap
  function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top
    var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = coor;
  }

  const canvas = document.querySelector('.heatmap')
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    getCursorPosition(canvas, e)
  })


  function printPage() {
    window.print();
  }

     </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of tinkering, I was able to figure it out: https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/p1kwrhmv

1. I used `img` and gave it a `background-image` with CSS.
2. I then set the heatmap layer to `relative` and the image layer to `absolute` using the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926626/positioning-an-image-behind-a-centered-div).
3. Last, I then set the image layer css using the method outlined [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211990/9311245).

   ```
   .heatmap {
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 100%;
     height: 300%; /*if the image is bigger than screen, this is needed */
     position: relative;
   }

   .backgroundIMG {
     background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Soccer_Field_Transparant.svg/1200px-Soccer_Field_Transparant.svg.png');
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     padding-top: 151.33%;
   }
   ```